# M3U8 plays with sound on one app but without sound on another

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have a user with an m3u8 file that the content of the file looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=701214,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.34",RESOLUTION=640x360
chunklist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1635263674
```

He claims this other app (not mine) is able to play that file with sound on the Chromecast whereas mine plays it without sound. I have not been able to reproduce his claims but since he insists this is true I figured I would check.

I'm using the reference player code pretty much unmodified except for this code which I got on this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256129/is-avc1-66-31-mp4a-40-2-supported-by-the-chromecast-device):

```
host.processManifest = function(manifest) {
    if (manifest) {
        return manifest.replace(/CODECS=\"avc1.66.([0-9]*)/g, 'CODECS=\"avc1.66.30');
    }else{
        return manifest;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you get the stream from that user and see if your app plays that or not? The change you have made shouldn't affect that stream since it is, based on your description, using avc1.66.30 already. It is possible that the other app is using a different receiver, or the app does some transcoding, etc but I would start with getting the stream from that person and trying it out and see where it fails.

Comment: This is the stream `http://evp.mm.uol.com.br:1935/band/brasilurgente/playlist.m3u8` but it goes down often so while I've been able to test it with my app and it plays (without sound), I haven't been able to do tons of troubleshooting. It is possible that the other app is doing transcoding although they don't advertise that on their store listing.

Comment: Can you download the stream to your own server so you can test the stream reliably (since you mentioned the stream goes down often)? Once you could create a reliable failure, you can open a ticket on our SDK issue tracker and include the stream and the receiver log so someone can take a look.

Comment: If I download just the .ts file, can the Chromecast play that?

Comment: I believe it should.

Comment: I got some segment files copied and the m3u8 files and I can reproduce the issue. I played it on VLC and looking at the codec information for audio it shows `Codec: MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga)`. Is that supported by the Chromecast?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a segment that exhibits this issue so we can try and debug it here?

Comment: Yeah, you can use https://341264b3031d6ca4e73d-211f6cddcd707817a7e4666cda84e0f2.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/video_no_sound.m3u8 but please let me know once you are done testing it so I can delete it. Thanks.

Comment: @AliNaddaf were you able to use that link? Thanks.

Comment: Please open an issue on our SDK issue tracker and include your stream and the receiver logs so we can take a look at this one.