# The type provided ('video/mp2t; codecs="avc1.100.42,mp4a.40.2"') is unsupported

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have a user trying to cast an m3u8 video and he keeps getting that error.

```
The type provided ('video/mp2t; codecs="avc1.100.42,mp4a.40.2"') is unsupported.
```

Is that codec supposed to be supported?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in some [threads](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=609) and [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278703/5995040), some builds of Chromecast were rejected so it is recommended to use supported media type like "avc1.66.30" instead. As stated in this [forum](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=398), a workaround would be trying to update the playlist or use `host.processManifest`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first two links are from me :) Anyways, I'm aware of the `host.processManifest` workaround, just a did a new one like an hour ago. I just don't know when I should do it and when I shouldn't do it. Hope that makes sense.